# отображение таблицы в jsp

Tags: html, jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>ListDeveloper</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col span="2" style="background:Khaki"><!-- С помощью этой конструкции задаем цвет фона для первых двух столбцов таблицы-->
        <col style="background-color:#ff564f">
        <col style="background-color:#33d1ff">
        <col style="background-color:#2cff23">
        <col style="background-color:#d94cff">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th >ID</th>
        <th >FIRST_NAME</td>
        <th >LAST_NAME</td>
        <th>SPECIALTY</td>
        <th>SKILLS</td>
        <th>ACCOUNTS</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
                <c:forEach items="${temp}" var="d" >
                    <td>${d.id}</td>
                    <td>${d.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${d.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${d.specialty}</td>
                    <c:forEach items="${d.skills}" var="trt">
                        <td>${trt.name}</td><br>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <td>${d.account.accountData}</td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Проблемы с выводом таблицы второй объект выводится не с новой строки тэг br не помогает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поместите tr внутрь forEach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно всего лишь поместить тег **tr** в середину цикла **forEach** чтобы сохранить структуру таблицы.

```
<c:forEach items="${temp}" var="d" >
    <tr>
        <td>${d.id}</td>
        <td>${d.firstName}</td>
        <td>${d.lastName}</td>
        <td>${d.specialty}</td>
        <c:forEach items="${d.skills}" var="trt">
            <td>${trt.name}</td><br>
        </c:forEach>
        <td>${d.account.accountData}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

tr в forEach поместите. Видно же, что этот элемент не в цикле у вас, потому и в рамках того же tr у вас добавляется второй элемент, «ломая» структуру таблицы.

Comment: надо отдохнуть немного)) спасибо